# Computer not entering POST?

Tags: motherboard, bios, post

I'm fairly clued up with this stuff but a bit rusty so bear with me haha.

Since I built the computer it has always had issues with POST if the cmos battery was ever removed it took a good 5 minutes to POST.

After a rather heated argument with me and said PC it seems to have got its self slightly damaged. It's refusing to POST at all. Fans come on lights come on all is good expect no display and no beeps even if I remove all RAM still no beeps so I know it's not entering POST.

Now here's the werid thing I can't find anything abkut online, I managed to get it to start (only one time never again) and get into BIOS obviously I go to change the date and time however it was already changing by its self rapidly to all different dates and all different times. I tried to change it and it froze.

mobo is ASrock N68C-S

I've tried;
● Removing Graphics Card 
● Changing RAM
● Changing Graphics Card
● Starting with no Hard Drive
● Reconnecting PSU

Comment: Learning what kind of motherboard might help. Please edit your question to give us an idea of what you are dealing with. You might try updating your BIOS for one thing. Be gentle with the said computer, the parts, memory, etc., are very fragile, and static from you touching things can destroy them. 1) make sure the computer's motherboard is completely without power before you touch anything, (no lights at all on the MOB). 2) unplug the extra stuff, usb hard disks etc., that is not needed in booting the computer. 3) Sometimes, just because a PSU acts like it is alright, does not make it so.

Comment: Hey Vssher, thanks for the reply. The mobo is ASrock N68C-S. I've tried unplugging evreything unneeded still no luck. Unfortunately I cannot update bios cant be done just now as I'm only getting a black display.  I was only able to get a display one time and in good it showed the date and time as constantly changing. Thanks again bro

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us, which type of CPU is installed, make sure you are not overclocking anything. Your MOB can only handle certain type of CPUs. Check here under support, is this one of your CPUs? I downloaded a manual of your motherboard, I have not read it yet. If _you_ don't have one, goto the site and download one, most of the time RAM can only be put in certain ways.  https://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68C-S/